# ¿Cómo redireccionar a mi web despues de realizada la compra?

Tags: nodejs, express

En mi servidor **node/express** hago un **redirect** a la a**pi mercadopago** para que el usuario haga la compra del producto. Al hacer el **redirect**, se abre la interfaz de la api donde el usuario pone sus datos de usuario, y decide la forma de pago(contado, tarjeta, etc..). Despues de que el usuario finaliza la compra, ¿Como se hace para que haga un **redirect a la web del frontend** ?.

intenté hacer esto, pero no hace nada:

```js
 try {
   // return res.status(200).json("recibido");

    // Crea un objeto de preferencia y cargo los productos
    let preference = {

      "back_urls": {
        "success": "https://www.tu-sitio/success",
        "failure": "https://www.goggle.com",
        "pending": "https://www.goggle.com"
    },
    "auto_return": "approved",

      items // items son productos que se van a comprar
       
    };

    mercadopago.preferences
      .create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        // redirije a pagina de mercadopago
        res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
        
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
```

Este es el código donde hace el redirect a la api para que haga la compra.

```js
export const prueba = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {

  try {
    // Crea un objeto de preferencia
    let preference = {
      items: [
        {
          // obteniendo los valores del formulario enviados desde Angular
          title: req.body.title.toString(),
          unit_price: parseInt(req.body.total.toString()),
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    };

    mercadopago.preferences
      .create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        // hace un redirect a pagina de mercadopago
        res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

Comment: Si tu lo estas redirigido a una página de mercadopago no podrás hacer nada, sin embargo mercadopago te da opciones para redireccionar según el estado de la compra si es satisfactorio a una página si es erróneo a otra y si esta 0endiente a otra. Eso esta en la [documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/integration#editor_13) sólo inicia sesión y sigue los pasos

Comment: Gracias por responder, entiendo lo que dices. el problema es que estuve investigando en la documentacion pero no encuentro un ejemplo.

Comment: Si hay, yo lo he echo pero con php, espera busco donde esta

Comment: dale gracias! si la encontras pasa el link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo la forma de hacerlo es con las `back_urls`

```
var preference = {}
preference = {
  // ...
  "back_urls": {
        "success": "https://www.tu-sitio/success",
        "failure": "http://www.tu-sitio/failure",
        "pending": "http://www.tu-sitio/pending"
    },
    "auto_return": "approved",
  // ...
}
```

Aquí te dejo la [documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/advanced-integration)

Comment: Bueno te sugiero que leas la documentación y veas bien los ejemplo que te dan

Comment: gracias excelente tu aporte!!, me habia olvidado un detalle y crei q estaba mal. El success funciona y gracias por la documentacion.

Comment: de nada @Claudio, que bueno haberte ayudado